# Regular Expression for Mobile and starting with 09 or 04

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi i wants to create the Regular expression for Mobile number

The data validation should require 10 numbers.
The data validation should require the first two numbers to be 04 or 09.

can any one help me on this , this is not working for me `/^09\d{8}$/`

this is the plunker wr my regex comming as string https://plnkr.co/edit/Yjch7G7npkHmtKYDF5Yc?p=preview

hi my regular expression already comming with quots how can i remove that `var regex = "/^0(9|4)d{8}$/"` like this :(

Comment: If you have no control over the var type of the pattern you receive, but you are sure it is always passed like that, you may use `var incoming="/^0[94]\\d{8}$/g";` and then 
`var regex = new RegExp(incoming.replace(/^\/(.*)\/g$/, "$1"));`. See [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/n1mva6XJYPwbHfxxl9Md?p=preview).

Comment: Did anything work for you?

Comment: hi yeah :) this one 0(9|4)\\d{8}

Comment: Then please consider accepting the answer that worked for you.

Comment: nothing here ..

Comment: Shouldn't the right answer be `var regex =new RegExp("^0(9|4)\\d{8}$")`? See [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/UadghkatuwScyctZcBeH?p=preview). I mean it should require a full string match, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This regex is working for me:

```
/^0(9|4)\d{8}$/
```

Explained:

```
^ - means start of line
0 - leading zero is mandatory
(9|4) - this is saying that the zero has to be followed by either a 9 or a 4
\d{8} - next, there have to be 8 digits
$ - means end of line
```

Comment: hi @ishegg thank you , can you please explain ow this work :)

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the answer. Let me know if you have any more doubts. Alternatively, you can post the regex in regex101.com and you'll get detailed explanations on how it works. You can also test the regex right there. It's a great website to test you regexes, and learn!

Comment: hi this is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Yjch7G7npkHmtKYDF5Yc?p=preview , where my regular expression is comming as string due to that its not working

Comment: @GayathriMohan, it is working. Don't add quotes to the RegExp constructor. You can see working code in this Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/WPBp7bdoO5z5U7EQRj2U?p=preview

Comment: hi @ishegg my regular expression already comming with quots how can i remove that regex = "/^0(9|4)d{8}$/" like this :(

Comment: Escape the characters. Use it like this: "/^0(4|9)\\d{8}/$"

Answer (score 1):

This regex is fairly simple and it works:

`/(09|04)\d{8}/g`

Explained:

- `(09|04)` says match the group (09|04) (a group is essentially a sequence to match), where the sequence to be matched is 09 OR (the `|` symbol) 04.
- Next, `\d{8}` says match exactly 8 digits following the `(09|04)` group.
- Finally, `g` sets the global flag (allowing for more than one match).

I hope this helped!

Comment: hi @Arthur-R this is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Yjch7G7npkHmtKYDF5Yc?p=preview , where my regular expression is comming as string due to that its not working

Comment: @Gayathri Mohan Hey, it looks like that in your plunker, you used `var regex2 = new RegExp("/(09|04)\d{8}/g");`, you shouldn't wrap regular expressions in quotes, if you change it to `var regex2 = new RegExp(/(09|04)\d{8}/g);` I believe it should work as intended.

Comment: hi @arthur_R my regulra expresion is string when i try to convert having an extra character added please check this in console regex = "/^0(9|4)d{8}$/"
new RegExp(regex);

Comment: @GayathriMohan Hey, it took me way longer than I expected to understand what was happening, but I believe the problem you have there is the string is the string you are passing into your regular expression has `d` instead of `\d`. If you try: ```let regex = "(9|4)\\d{8}";
let regexVal = new RegExp(regex, 'g');
const str = 0911223344 + "";
console.log(str.search(regexVal));``` It should work fine. Note that this example should print something other than -1 to the console to confirm the regex matched. If you put in `\d` and its still coming out as `d` try escaping it with `\\d` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

```
var regex = /^0(9|4)\d{8}$/
alert(regex.test('0412345678')); //true
alert(regex.test('0912345678')); //true
alert(regex.test('0512345678')); //false

var regex = new RegExp(/^0(9|4)\d{8}$/);
alert(regex.test('0412345678')); //true
alert(regex.test('0912345678')); //true
alert(regex.test('0512345678')); //false
```

Comment: hi  @PraveenKumar this is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Yjch7G7npkHmtKYDF5Yc?p=preview , where my regular expression is comming as string due to that its not working

Comment: change var regex =new RegExp("/^0(9|4)\d{8}$/"); to var regex =new RegExp(/^0(9|4)\d{8}$/);

Comment: hi i changed also still retuing as some extra characters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706282/regular-expression-is-not-working-due-to-the-pattern-is-string

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net code Entity you can use following code:

```
RegularExpression(@"^0(9|4)[0-9\d]{8}$", ErrorMessage = "Your message")]
```